# If $Q\ltimes P$ is a Schmidt group with abelian $P$ and cyclic $Q$, then $\phi(P)$ is trivial.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a Schmidt group. Suppose that $G=Q\ltimes P$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $Q=\langle a \rangle$ is a cyclic Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$.  Prove that if $P$ is abelian, then $\phi(P)=1$.

Comment: What's a Schmidt group? And what is your question?

Comment: @ChrisGodsil A Schmidt group is a non-nilpotent finite group in which each proper subgroup is nilpotent.

Answer (score 2):

If not, then $\Phi(P) \rtimes Q$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and hence nilpotent, so $\Phi(P) \le C_P(Q)$. Now there is a general result (for finite groups) that  if a $p'$-group $Q$ acts on an abelian $p$-group $P$, then $P = C_P(Q) \times [P,Q]$. But then $[P,Q] \rtimes Q$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ and hence it is nilpotent, so $[P,Q] \le C_P(Q)$, contradiction.

Comment: tank you. I read your proof. I couldn't learn. Can i explain more? Why  $\Phi(P) \le C_P(Q)$ ? Which act?

Comment: $\Phi(P) \le C_P(Q)$ follows immediately from the fact that $\Phi(P) \rtimes Q$ is nilpotent, $\Phi(P)$ is a $p$-group, and $Q$ is a $q$-group with $q \ne p$.

Comment: Tank you. Tell me a book to read this theorem. I not saw this.